# How to put a imagebutton/imageview between a multiline textview in android

Tags: android, android-webview, android-imageview, textview, multiline

I am having an issue of placing a imagebutton/imageview between a multiline textview in Android.

Eg.:

[image]

The text is dynamic. I am having many views like this in my application(nearly 50) with different texts and I want to achieve this with re-usability of code. So kindly suggest me some dynamic solution. On clicking the imagebutton/imageview, it should redirect to calling screen.

I am open to ideas of performing this with the help of WebViews unless and until they handle the dynamicity of text throughout the application(I don't want to make Html file for each and every view).

Looking for the sincere co-operation. Thank You.

Comment: Use SpannableString, to achieve this.. search on google about the same

Comment: @Pragnani- Can I put ImageView between lines in that..?? Coz I have seen that but didn't think that would make it possible.

Comment: yes you can place image in between text

Comment: Can u please give me the demo code of that and please post that as an answer so that I can accept it..thanks

Comment: I have posted a sample code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
        SpannableString string1=new SpannableString(yourdynamictext);

//Get Drawable
             Drawable d=getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        d.setBounds(0,0,d.getIntrinsicWidth(),d.getIntrinsicHeight());

// image span
        ImageSpan span2= new ImageSpan(d,ImageSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE);
            string1.setSpan(span2, 0, 4, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
       yourtextview.setText(string1);
```

Update:

**set this  for your textview**

```
yourtexview.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Use **ClickableSpan**

Here is the example

```
 ClickableSpan clickableSpan = new ClickableSpan() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View textView) {
                   Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Hello",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            };


           string1.setSpan(clickableSpan , 0, 4, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
           yourtextview.setText(string1);
```

Comment: That is exactly what I wanted..but just one question, how to put an onClickListwner on that image..??

Comment: @NilayOnAndroid Don't forgot to add movement method to your textview, `yourtexview.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());`

Comment: Replacing this line "string1.setSpan(clickableSpan , 0, 4, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);" removes the ImageSpan from text ! I want the image and onClickListener on that image ??

Comment: @NilayOnAndroid sry for the late reply.. you need to keep both..don't remove image span

Comment: Thank you very much. Just what I wanted !!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to set two spans: imagespan and ClickableSpan like this.

```
fun TextView.setIconifiedText(text: String, @DrawableRes iconResId: Int) {
    val clickableSpan: ClickableSpan = object : ClickableSpan() {
        override fun onClick(textView: View) {
            Log.d("", "onClick: ")
        }
    }
    SpannableStringBuilder("$text#").apply {
        setSpan(
            ImageSpan(context, iconResId, DynamicDrawableSpan.ALIGN_BOTTOM),
            text.length,
            text.length + 1,
            Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
        )
        setSpan(clickableSpan, text.length, text.length + 1, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
    }.let {
        setText(it)
        movementMethod = LinkMovementMethod.getInstance()
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
textView.setIconifiedText("your text", R.drawable.icon);
```